# getting the src of a link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a link like :

```
<a rel="Test Images" class="thickbox preview_link" href="http://www.localhost.com:8080/testwp/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/2013-10-02_1728.png">
```

i need to get the url of that image inside a javascript file loaded on the same page.

i tried something like:

```
image_src = jQuery('a[class=thickbox preview_link]').attr('href');
```

but all i get is Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[class=thickbox preview_link] in the console.

i am using jquery 1.10.2 on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
jQuery('a.thickbox.preview_link').attr('href');
```

Your attribute selector syntax is incorrect since it has space you need to wrap them in quotes (`'a[class="thickbox preview_link"]'`), but you can always use class selector which would be mostly faster than the attribute selector and the order doesn't matter as well.

Comment: But they aren't actually the same though

Comment: @Musa ofcourse they aren't you dont have to use attribute selector in this case. Atleast it has more disadvantages than advantages in this case i would think....

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need it, here's the vanilla Javascript version

Get the image(s)

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('thickbox preview_link');
```

Getting the href (of the first image)

```
var image_href = image[0].getAttribute('href');
```

Better version

```
// Declare the image_href variable
var image_href;

// Getting a nodeList of all the applicable images
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('thickbox preview_link');

// If there's only 1 image and/or you only want the first one's href
if(image[0] !== undefined) {
    // if condition to check whether or not the DOM has the images in the first place
    // if yes, update the image_href variable with the href attribute
    image_href = image[0].getAttribute('href');
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

`thickbox preview_link` is actually **2** class tokens, so you're looking for `a.thickbox.preview_link` or (for that specific attribute) `a[class="thickbox preview_link"]` (notice the quotes)

```
image_src = jQuery('a.thickbox.preview_link').attr('href');
// or 
image_src = jQuery('a[class="thickbox preview_link"]').attr('href');
```